# Using Korean in python FPDF

Tags: python, pdf, fonts, fpdf, cjk

I have an project with Python FPDF.

A document with English was generated successfully.

But, not Korean..

Do you know how to use Korean through Python FPDF???

I have tried to install Korean fonts in my computer. But it didn't work.

Comment: Wouldn't be a problem with PyMuPDF ... .

Comment: You need to use a font that supports Korean.